# create AWS EC2 Linux service's machine as Jenkins master and local Windows machine as slave

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-agent, jenkins-mstest

I have created EC2 Linux service and install Jenkins on it. Also installed Jenkins on my local windows machine. I want to create Linux server as master and Windows system as Slave in Jenkins.

When I tried to connect master and slave, I got an error.

Image of error is  as below:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.

Problem was need to allow 36033 port on EC2 Linux service.

Please find below steps to allow the port.
1. select Linux service and check security group in description tab.
2. Go to Security group and in Inbound tab click on edit
3. Add new Rule
4. Select All TCP in Type and save it(This will allow all the port you can allow specific port also using selecting Custom TCP Rule and in port add your port).

Reboot the service and download slave-agent.jnlp and try to connect again.